# Custom print of a timestamp field

Tags: java, mysql

I got table with a timestamp field in my mysql db.
I would like to print in java just the hour and minutes in this format HH:MM .

How can I do that?
Printing the timestamp without any change would look like that:

```
2013-01-29 11:05:00
```

I tagged java since I would like to do that in java.

Comment: You should use a [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). [simpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) allows you format dates as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat is what you want

```
String date = "2013-01-29 11:05:00";

SimpleDateFormat parsedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat printedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date a = parsedFormat.parse(date);
System.out.println(printedFormat.format(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL to format the date.

For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS showdate FROM table
```

You can use http://www.mysqlformatdate.com to get the correct format you need.